# jQuery - Datepicker always showing up on bottom of screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the datepicker plugin from jQuery and it has been working nicely. However, recently, I noticed that it is always present in the bottom left corner of the browser window -- but without the proper formatting (it's transparent and ugly). See this screenshot of it: [image]

Also -- and I think this is related -- all my tooltips are now *always* on the far left edge of the screen and is also missing the proper formatting.

The tooltips only show up when they are supposed to, but pinned to the left edge and without formatting. And, the datepicker does show up when I click into a date field -- but also without proper formatting. The datepicker does remain on the bottom left of the screen after I've chosen my date.

Any idea what's happening? I feel like I'm missing some sort of jQuery linkage either to the actual script or to the CSS. It seems that my

Comment: It looks like you are missing jquery css entirely

Comment: Close, I had the CSS, but the perms were wrong. I've added a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Classic. Right after posting I had the "ah-ha" moment.

For any one else with this issue, it turned out that my permissions for the CSS file I was using were wrong. I had to set the perms on the jquery-custom-theme.css to allow anyone to read it. Now everything is back to normal.

Problem Solved.